# Undefined result from JavaScript BinarySearch

Tags: javascript, binary-search

```
function binarySearch(items, target){
var startIndex = 0, 
stopIndex = items.length-1,
middle = Math.floor((stopIndex+startIndex)/2); 
debugger;
while(items[middle]!=target && startIndex<stopIndex){
    if(target<items[middle]){
        stopIndex = middle-1;       
    } else if(target>items[middle]){
        startIndex = middle+1;
    }
    middle = Math.floor((stopIndex+startIndex)/2);
}}
```

I wrote another function to use above binarySearch() and that one is

```
function getValue(){
var items = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
alert(binarySearch(items,"i"));}
```

And I call this getValue() from HTML like this

```
<button onclick="getValue()">Click to find the binary</button>
```

When I click the button, it alerts the 'undefine'.

Actually, I am learning, so I couldnot understand properly how to pass value, how to call the function to get expected value. 
If anyone helps me to understand and to solve this it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to `return` results from functions?

Comment: No, that's why I asked how to get the value from the function.  I want to know. Can you please help me to understandt?

Comment: Which "the value"? You need to specify using a [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from your function. After your loop is finished running you need to return what you found.

```
function binarySearch(items, target){
    var startIndex = 0, 
    stopIndex = items.length-1,
    middle = Math.floor((stopIndex+startIndex)/2); 
    debugger;
    while(items[middle]!=target && startIndex<stopIndex){
        if(target<items[middle]){
            stopIndex = middle-1;       
        } else if(target>items[middle]){
            startIndex = middle+1;
        }
        middle = Math.floor((stopIndex+startIndex)/2);
    }
    return (items[middle] !== target) ? -1 : middle;
}
```

The return line uses the the [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator it's equivalent to an if statement.

Comment: Thanks, Why I have to return? I didn't get this. Sorry for the silly question. But want to understand.

Comment: @Garten786 The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller. Without it you are just running the search and not returning anything from the function call. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)